# Bloquear/esmaecer tela durante o postback

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net

Sei que para efetuar este efeito de bloquear/esmaecer posso usar JavaSscript ou alguns componente do AJAX.

Acho interessante este tipo de cuidado para evitar que o usuário fique clicando várias vezes no mesmo botão o que pode gerar problemas. Além de dar um indicativo de que o processamento ainda esta ocorrendo.

Qual seria a abordagem mais indicada, JavaScript, AJAX ou existe outra forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendo uma aplicação web, necessariamente com javascript e ajax, um complementa o outro. Você pode usar plugins como jquery.UI para facilitar o seu trabalho!

Comment: Até fiz com JavaScript só quero ter certeza do melhor método para evitar ter retrabalho. Vou pesquisar sobre jQuery.UI.

Answer (score 3):

Uma abordagem que você pode tentar é colocar todos os seus controles com os quais o usuário pode interagir em um [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Isso cuida da parte do Ajax, já que os controles para Ajax encasulam toda a lógica de comunicação com o servidor.

No clique de um botão que esteja dentro do `UpdatePanel` e que faça o postback, você chama uma função Javascript que faça algo do tipo:

- criar uma *div* semi-transparente que cobre o seu conteúdo (provavelmente com posicionamento absoluto ou fixado). A *div* protege os demais controles sob ela contra cliques;
- atribuir uma cor a essa *div*, ou desabilitar todos os controles, ou qualquer outra coisa que dê ao usuário a ideia de que os controles não são utilizáveis no momento;
- finalmente, quando vier a resposta do postback, você chama outra função javascript que desfaz o que foi feito nos passos acima.

Comment: Eu uso o UpdatePanel então já estaria encaminhado. Só que tive problemas com botão de download dentro do UpdatePanel, tive que colocar fora dele, pois não estava funcionando. Pelo que entendi só funciona com cotroles dentre do UpdatePanel. A ideia seria jogar uma div para bloquear a tela toda sem necessidade de desabilitar os controles. Até consegui fazer com Javascritp, mas queri me certificar do melhor caminho a seguir.